# How to increase on the size of the leading icon off an AppBar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

I am looking for a way of increasing the size of  Appbar leading Icon. Below is my code 
:

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(120.0),
              child: AppBar(
                leading: SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                height: 200,
                child: IconButton(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/app_logo.png', height: 700.0, width: 700.0,)
                  ,
                )),
            centerTitle: true,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/path.png'))
            ],
            bottom: TabBar(
                labelColor: Colors.white,
                indicatorColor: Colors.lime,

                tabs:[
                  Tab(icon: null,text: 'RECENT',),
                  Tab(icon: null, text: 'TOPICS',),
                  Tab(icon: null, text: 'AUTHORS',),
                ]
            ),
          )
```

From the code above, specifically the size I implemented is below, but it couldn't work :

```
child: AppBar(
                    leading: SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    child: IconButton(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      icon: Image.asset('assets/app_logo.png', height: 700.0, width: 700.0,)
                      ,
                    )),
```

***My goal is to increase the Right top icon more bigger, but it doesn't increase it's size.***

The screenshot is as below :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increase the size of the icon by wrapping `IconButton` with `Transform.scale` and pass `scale` value as 2, depending on how big you want the icon to be. Working sample code below:

```
centerTitle: true,
                actions: <Widget>[
                  Transform.scale(
                    scale: 2,
                    child: IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/placeholder.png'))
                  ),

                ],
```

This increases size of the top right icon in the appbar, as:

[image]

You may adjust the scale per your need and also can apply same change to top left icon too.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks so much , it did the magic, though can you also help me to give me some clues about doing the margin of the left side

Answer (score 3):

Using Transform.scale is not quite right, there is an easier way to get the desired effect.

```dart
AppBar(
    toolbarHeight: 100,    //set height appBar
    leading: Image.asset('image/my_logo.png', width: 120, height: 100), //insert logo image
    leadingWidth: 120, //set leading height. By default width is 56
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you Can Increase or decrease Image or IconSize by using Transform.scale widget

```
 appBar: AppBar(
    leading: Transform.scale(
      scale: 0.5,
      child: Image.asset(AppAssetsConfig.MenuIcon)),
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    elevation: 0,
```

backgroundColor: Color(BasicAppColor.primaryColor),
),